# Applescript command in document class

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to create an applescript command in my document class. I know I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure how to do this.

From what I understand (which may be incorrect), when I create a new command
I need to specify a new class for that command. But from that new class, lets call it
`ScriptResetCommand`, how do I access the document object from the `performDefaultImplementation` method? The applescript call is something like

```
tell document 1 of application "DocScript" to simple reset
```

Here is my current code:
**ScriptResetCommand.m file:**

```
@implementation ScriptResetCommand
- (id)performDefaultImplementation {
    // Somehow I need to access the correct document class and
    // perform my reset.
    NSLog(@"ScriptResetCommand performDefaultImplementation");
    return @"Reset Stuff";
}
```

**ScriptResetCommand.h file:**

```
@interface ScriptResetCommand : NSScriptCommand
- (id)performDefaultImplementation;
```

**.sdef file:**

```
    <command name="simple reset" code="jDsgSrst" description="run a simple reset">
        <cocoa class="ScriptResetCommand"/>
        <result type="text" description="returns the result"/>
    </command>
```

So with this code, I can successfully call the `performDefaultImplementation` method in the `ScriptResetCommand` class, but how do I then access the `Document` object which has the desired `reset` command in it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the document object using the method `-[NSScriptCommand evaluatedReceivers]`. Try something like this:

```
- (id)performDefaultImplementation {
    NSDocument *document = [self.evaluatedReceivers firstObject];
    if (![document isKindOfClass:[NSDocument class]]) {
        // I'm just guessing how this error should be handled; untested (for example, you'll want to make sure your app returns an error if you run "reset stuff" without specifying a document)
        [self setScriptErrorExpectedTypeDescriptor:[NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithTypeCode:cDocument]];
        return nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"Got document: %@", document);

    return @"Reset Stuff";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  For some reason, the document object above is a nil. I also tried  `NSDocument *doc2 = [self directParameter];` which returns nil also.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried debugging by printing `self. receiversSpecifier`, `self.arguments`, and `self.evaluatedArguments`? One of those might have something interesting. See https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScriptCommand_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScriptCommand/evaluatedArguments

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what

```
tell document 1 of application "DocScript" to simple reset
```

would do, but to process it, break it down into a verb (simple reset) and a target (document 1 of application "DocScript"). When the command is executed, a reference to the target will be provided in [command directParameter], from which you can get an objectSpecifier for your document.

Here's how I implemented text selection in my scriptable text editor, Ted. The verb (command) is "select" and the target is "paragraph 5 of document 1".

```
tell application "Ted"
    select paragraph 5 of document 1
end tell
```

SDEF: The command is defined in the Text Suite objects:

```
<suite name="Text Suite" code="????">
    ...
    <class name="paragraph" code="cpar" inherits="item" >
        ...
        <responds-to command="select">
            <cocoa method="handleSelectCommand:"/>
        </responds-to>
    </class>
    ...
</suite>
```

The "select" command actually is included for EVERY class in the text suite that can be selected: e.g. paragraph, line, word, character.

Implementation:

Since all the various scriptable text objects are represented as NSTextStorage classes, I just use a category on NSTextStorage to implement the command.

```
@implementation NSTextStorage (Scriptability)
-   (void) handleSelectCommand:(NSScriptCommand *)command
{
    NSScriptObjectSpecifier *directParameter =[command directParameter];

    NSScriptObjectSpecifier *container = [directParameter containerSpecifier];

    TedDocument *document = [self extractDocument:container];

    NSString *contents = document.textView.string;
    NSRange selRange;

    [self getRangeForSelectCommand:directParameter contents:contents range:&selRange];

    [document.textView setSelectedRange:selRange];
}
@end
```

A reference to the document is provided by the **directParameter**, but it is part of a containment hierarchy, in this case 'paragraph 5 of document 1 of application "Ted"', so we need a method to walk that hierarchy to extract the document from it. Here is that function:

// Navigate the containment hierarch using recursion, if necessary.

```
- (TedDocument *) extractDocument:(NSScriptObjectSpecifier *)container
{
    if (container == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"ERROR: extractDocument received nil container reference");

        return nil;
    }

    FourCharCode containerClass =  [[container keyClassDescription] appleEventCode];

    if (containerClass != 'docu')
    {
        return [self extractDocument:[container containerSpecifier]];
    }

    return [container objectsByEvaluatingSpecifier];
}
```